# Spring+Thymeleaf upload file in form with other data

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, multipartform-data

I've created a Thymeleaf form with some input data (name, surname, mail...) and an input of type "file".

form:

```
<form class="inp-form" id="insertInterview" action="#" th:action="@{/interview/create}" th:object="${createInterviewTO}" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
              <div class="2-column-container">
                     <div class="row">
                         <div class="column">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                           <input type="text" th:field="*{candidateName}" placeholder="Name" />
                                                    <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('candidateSurname')}" th:errors="*{candidateName}">Name Error</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Surname</label>
                                                    <input type="text" th:field="*{candidateSurname}" placeholder="Surname" />
                                                    <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('candidateSurname')}" th:errors="*{candidateSurname}">Surname Error</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Curriculum</label>
                                                    <input type="file" id="cv" name="curriculum" accept="pdf" />
                                                    <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cv')}" th:errors="*{cv}">CV Error</small>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Input data is actually stored in a custom object called CreateInterviewTO, file business logic is actually not implemented.

```
    @PostMapping("/create")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> createInterview(@RequestBody @ModelAttribute CreateInterviewTO createInterviewTO) {
....................
}
```

How can I change my code due to accept also the file (Multipart) and process it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add a property to the dto

```
public class CreateInterviewTO {

    // ...
    private MultipartFile curriculum;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

and change method to

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> createInterview(@ModelAttribute CreateInterviewTO createInterviewTO, ModelMap modelMap) {

    // ...
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Comment: I've added the curriculum attribute and the following code to html:
<input type="file" th:field="*{curriculum}" id="cv" accept="pdf" />
But the "curriculum" attribute in DTO is ever null.

Comment: read the provided link, end of section 6.. no need to use th:field, try name="curriculum"